# The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to upgrade the `targetSdkVersion` of the `APP` I am in charge of from `30` to `31`.

I keep getting this error when I try to install it on my test cell phone:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZlPo.png)]

I looked through the logcat by referring to other articles with similar symptoms, but there is no `271`rd line in my manifests.

Below is my logcat error part.

[image]

I added `android`, exported to all items in manifest, upgraded `Gradle` Version to `6.1.1` and `Gradle` plugin to `4.0.1` but I still get this error.

There are no capital letters in the path.